# How to add sample xml payload to web service documentation using apache cxf?

Tags: web-services, cxf

We are trying to use the Apache CXF to document our webservice using the @WSDLDocumentationCollection and @WSDLDocumentation annotations. As part of the PORT_TYPE_OPERATION documentation we are planning to add a sample XML payload to the documentation. However when we do so "<" character is escaped while the ">" character is not. Also, we are unable to add newline characters to our documentation. Is this a limitation of CXF or is there some way to have a CDATA in the generated documentation?